# Linking Lua with Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, lua

I am a noob so if what I am asking is straight forward, or something basic that I have missed, please excuse me.

Im trying to link Lua with Qt creator so that I can run a basic Lua script. I included all of the header files required by Lua in my main.cpp file. And low I'm trying to link the liblua.a library to the project; so what I did is, I manually added the library.
The Creator then generated this code, and added it to my .pro - file :

```
    unix:!macx: LIBS += L$$PWD/ -llua

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

    unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/liblua.a
```

Then when I start the debugger, I get two errors:

-Skipping incompatible /home/..path to Lua source files../liblua.a when searching for -llua

-cannot find -llua

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and the version of Lua that I'm currently working with is 5.2.3

Can someone please advise me as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Compile Output:
        16:48:10: Running steps for project testApp...
        16:48:10: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.

```
    16:48:10: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 

    arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.4-arm/lib -o 
    testApp main.o    -L/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.4-arm/lib -ldl -L/home/david
    /workspace/testApp/ -llua -lQtNetwork -L/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.4-
    arm/lib -lQtCore -lpthread 

    /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: 
    skipping incompatible /home/david/workspace/testApp//liblua.a when searching for 
    -llua

    /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot 
    find -llua

    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    make: *** [testApp] Error 1

    16:48:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.

    Error while building/deploying project testApp (kit: SAP)

    When executing step 'Make'

    16:48:10: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Comment: Where does your lib placed relatively to .pro file? If in teh same directory then just try to replace generated code with simple `LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -llua`

Comment: "Skipping Incompatible" typically means that you're using a 32 bit library on a 64 bit compile, or vice versa. Double check your `lua` library.

Comment: @dvvrd , I moved it to the same file as the .pro file , then I tried your advice, still got the same error.

Comment: @TylerJandreau , Im running 32-bit ubuntu and 32-bit Qt creator, and I just confirmed that the lua lua library is 32-bit as well.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. I can't help more without knowing more about your build environment.

Comment: @Daveman, at least copy here a part of complie output

Comment: @TylerJandreau, Im using Qt version 4.8.4 (Qt-embedded-4.8.4-arm), and ARM GCC compiler. We're programming an ARM core in c++, and now we want to be able to run Lua scripts on the existing software. (don't know if that helps you)

Comment: @dvvrd , Added Compile Output

Comment: @Daveman, maybe lua lib itself is not compiled under arm target or smth?

Comment: @dvvrd , I think your're right; that might be the problem. I'm having no success trying to cross compile for the ARM target so far.
Will update when we figure something out
(currently we're checking whether we van get eLua to run on our ARM mcu)

Comment: @dvvrd , thank you very much for the advice; it took me a while to get the lua library cross compiled; but eventually I did, and it is now working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Daveman might be worth summarizing this into a short answer so it is flagged as answered plus then people don't have to read gobs of comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it solved!

The problem was that that I had to cross compile the Lua library for the ARM core. The architecture of the original Lua library was not recognizable by the core, as the execution of the program took place on the core itself when debugging.

I did this by :

```
    $ make linux CC=PATH/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc AR=”PATH/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar rcu”  RANLIB=PATH/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
```

and removing all references to readline in the makefile and config file before executing above command.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your exaplanation? I have installed all QT 5.3 stuff into `/opt/android`, so that I have the directories `android-ndk-r9d`, `android-sdk-linux` and `Qt5.3.0_RC_2014`. I'd like to call Lua scripts from some widget.