# Linking Lua with C++ in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, lua, qt-creator

Currently I'm trying to link a Lua script with the host C++ Application. For my Lua Script all I have in it is:

```
io.write(string.format("From Lua."));
```

I'm using Qt creator for this and trying to call on the script like so:

```
lua_State *state = luaL_newstate();
lua_call(state , 0 , 0);
```

Which keeps giving me a `PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a string value)` error.

I've tried wrapping the script in a function like so:

```
function main()

io.write(string.format("From Lua.With Progress"));


end
```

And then calling it with the same code as before but with an added:

```
lua_getglobal(state , "main");
lua_pcall(state , 0 , 0 , 0);
```

which gives no error but:

```
lua_call(state , 0 , 0)
```

gives a `PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)` error.

After more trouble shooting I found out that `luaL_loadfile(state , "EngineRxer.lua")`  is returning value 7 instead of 0, so I'm under the assumption that the script failed to load in the first place.

I also checked my run working directory in Qt Creator *projects -> Build and run ->run* and they're in the same directory as the Lua script.

I've referred to:

[Linking Lua with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132898/linking-lua-with-qt)

[Qt with Lua | Where to place lua file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667309/qt-with-lua-where-to-place-lua-files)

And even some Qt forums:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60693-Can-not-use-Lua-in-QtCreator

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/62772-Lua-into-Qt

Also, It's probably important to mention what my .pro file looks like, all Lua libraries and includes are already in there:

```
LIBS += \
/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.3.4_3/lib/liblua.5.3.4.dylib

INCLUDEPATH += \
    /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.3.4_3/include
```

Even more importantly, after more troubleshooting, I decided to make a dummy test project on Netbeans (NonQt just CML) and it ran and worked just fine. Even if I try and make a dummy `fstream` program to write to an empty .txt file, it won't know where to find it. So I'm suspecting this to be a Qt Creator problem, but I have all my paths and build directories pointed to CWD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works for me:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    const char* script = "io.write(\"From Lua\")"; // or read the string from a user, file, etc.
    if(luaL_loadstring(L, script) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        //error occured
        const char* s = luaL_checkstring(L, -1);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in script: %s", s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    lua_close(L);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Have you remembered to call `luaL_openlibs` and load your script?

Remember to check the return value from `lua_load*` and `lua_pcall`. They will place an error message on the top of the stack which you can read and display to the user.

Also look at the documentation for [luaL_loadfile](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadfile):

> This function returns the same results as lua_load, but it has an extra error code LUA_ERRFILE if it cannot open/read the file.

Looking in the `lauxlib.h` header (for lua 5.3), we see that `LUA_ERRFILE` is equal to `LUA_ERRERR+1`, which is defined in `lua.h` as 6. Therefore `LUA_ERRFILE` is equal to 7 (in Lua 5.3; other versions may vary).

Therefore it looks like you are not specifying the file name correctly, or the script is otherwise not readable. Try opening the file with a QFile or std::ifstream and printing it to the console to ensure that you're specifying your paths correctly.

Comment: Should mention, changing `lua_call` to  `lua_pcall` did the trick.